# How to set value to datepicker jquery ui with php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, jquery-ui-datepicker

Thanks for attention ,I have date range filter on website.where two Date-picker inputs are mentioned ,first one is for start date and second is for end date.i am using data-table for min and max range function.Everything work fine on click event.Now i want to set date-picker value from php $_GET and run the function on window load.my date format is `Fab-02-18` 
More Clear, here is proper funciton code onjsfiddle. just i want to make in php form filter.[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2bkbx2y3/180/)

Here is inputs fields

```
<label><input type="text" name="min" id="min" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" value="Feb-21-18"  ></label>
<label><input type="text" name="max" id="max" class="form-control" placeholder="End Date" value="Jan-02-18" ></label>
```

Here is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {

    var  min = $('#min').datepicker('setDate', <?php echo $_GET['min']; ?>);
    var  max = $('#max').datepicker('setDate', <?php echo $_GET['max']; ?>);
    alert(min);

        var startDate = new Date(data[10]);
        if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
        if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true;}
        if(max == null && startDate >= min) {return true;}
        if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
    );

        $("#min").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
        $("#max").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
        var table = $('#html-table').DataTable();

        // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
        $('#min, #max').change(function () {
            table.draw();

        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the values from php either with an ajax call, or by sending them in the document in both cases after you get the values you can set the default values to your dates and table... with this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/3kepedes/)

```
    $('#min').datepicker( "setDate" , "Feb-01-18" );
    $('#max').datepicker( "setDate" , "Mar-02-18" );
    table.draw();
```

If you set this inside document.ready, you are saying run this after the dom is ready, but you can also use window.onload

```
window.onload = function() {
   $('#min').datepicker( "setDate" , "Feb-01-18" );
   $('#max').datepicker( "setDate" , "Mar-02-18" );
   table.draw();
};
```

This will run after all your element, images are set up..

Comment: okay but how can i make this function on window load event.when user click on form submit button.

Answer (score 0):

If your jquery code is in `.js` file it won't work, you need to embed you js in a `.php` file.

Comment: no, it not on separate .js file.i write script on php page.